# How to reduce size of WASM binary?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, webassembly, wasi

I have a project written in C++, and the platform to be deployed in has a limitation of 256KB of binary size.

The toolchain is wasi-sdk-16.0 clang++, we use this compiler to compile the source code into binary in WASM format. In this step we compile the sources with the following CXX_FLAGS.

```
-fstack-protector-strong -Os -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wno-psabi
```

Then we `strip` the binary with

```
strip -s output_binary.wasm
```

After steps above, the compiled binary size in this step is 254KB.

Then we use `wamrc` in WAMR to compile the WASM binary with AOT runtime, the command is shown below.

```
wamrc --enable-indirect-mode --disable-llvm-intrinsics -o output.aot output.wasm
```

the output binary size become 428KB, much bigger than the limitation (256KB).

---

After google'd, I use `wasm-opt` to reduce size,

```
wasm-opt -Oz output.wasm -o output.wasm
```

The size become 4KB smaller. (almost useless)

---

I tried to comfirm how much does my code affects the binary size, so I write simple minimum sample code just called the standard c++ library, as the following,

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (auto v: vec) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
}
```

The binary size after compiled has alrealy become 205KB.

---

I also tried to use a binary size profiler (`twiggy`) to track the size of each part of the bianry, but the tool failed to open this binary.

---

So I want to ask

1. While just including two standard C++ headers makes the binary size reach the size limitation, how can I strip the C++ standard library with the function I really use(I cannot use strip unused function flag because my project is a library provide to others), or is really the c++ standard library affected the binary size?
2. Is there any other compiler flags, or strip flags, or any other optimization tools can significantly reduce the binary size?

Comment: C++ `iostream` is pretty bulky, involving a lot of library code.  It matters a lot *which* two headers you used; e.g. `#include <algorithm>` would only be template functions so you'd only pay for what you use.  Same with `#include <vector>`; it's pretty light weight.

Comment: Try building everything with LTO (Link Time Optimization) enabled. Besides usually producing faster code it also often results in smaller binaries.

Comment: The linker can also do some optimizations of its own (besides LTO). You can enable those with `-Wl,-O` and that can sometimes also reduce binary size (a bit).

Comment: Also look into the `--gc-sections` linker option. It may be of use to you.

Comment: Although the `-Os` compiler option is supposed to optimize for size, it does not always result in the smallest possible binary. Try experimenting with `-Og`, `-O1`, `-O2` & `-O3` as well.

Comment: You can often save space by rearranging your `struct`/`class` members such that you reduce the amount of padding the compiler has to insert between members. This can often save a lot of space for non-trivial programs. See for example https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=requirements-arranging-variables-reduce-padding

Comment: Another thing you can do is to ensure that only functions / types that you *need* to export have  non-hidden visibility. See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: Declaring `struct`s and `class`s that you do not need/want to inherit from as `final` can also in some cases help the compilers optimizer to generate faster and sometimes smaller code.

Comment: The `-Oz` compiler option is supposed to more aggressively optimize for size than `-Os` - give it a try.

Comment: Also check out the [sstrip](https://github.com/aunali1/super-strip) tool as a way to possibly shave off a few more bytes from your files.

Comment: Instead of editing an answer into the question, please post your answers as a proper answer to the question.  You can even click the accept checkmark on your own answer to show future readers it's what worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I solve this issue with just replacing iostream and fstream to cstdio. It reduces size from 254KB to 85KB, because there contains too many templates in iostream.**

| Using `iostream` | Count of functions (with `readelf -Ws`) | Size of Binary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 685 | 254KB |
| No | 76 | 85KB |

---

While specifying compiler flags such as -Oz also reduces some size, but the main factor is too many codes were generated from templates. So, do not use C++ stream API (and any other template-heavy general-purpose libraries) when there are binary size limitations. (C libraries are always worth to believe.)

Comment: You would think that a high level of optimization would cause the compiler to inline all the templates

Answer (score 2):

One of the things I didn't see mentioned in your post is [wabt](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt)'s `wasm-strip`. I am not familiar enough with it to know if it does more than the simple `strip` command, but maybe it is worth a try. You can install it with `apt install wasm-strip` on a Debian system.

From the few micro-benchmarks I see on the internet, C++ wasm binaries have large overhead. For a totally-not-scientific slide you can watch [this](https://youtu.be/J5Rs9oG3FdI?t=2167).

If, for whatever reason, you cannot work the language to produce smaller binaries, you may try to optimize also at the link level, as [busybox](https://busybox.net/use_less_ram.html) does.